# INTEGER (0..2**24 - 1) is uint32_t & 0xFFFFFF?

Tags: c

I found a type of variable that has a value of INTEGER (0...2<sup>24</sup> - 1). a guy who made the code decide to put a variable with type of uint32_t var; and put the result of this with 0xFFFFFF

how does this uint32_t & OxFFFFFF is able to handle the value of INTEGER (0...2<sup>24</sup> - 1) ?

As I understand, with masking 0xFFFFFF you make the value to be all positive (or?) but how does this thing work, I think I miss a concept here.

Comment: It would help if you'd say which language you're talking about...

Comment: What does `INTEGER (0...2(24) - 1))` mean/stand for?

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan: `2(24)` is `2^24` or `pow(2,24)`. `2(24)-1` is 0xffffff. The type is an unsigned 24-bit integer.

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan : it has value from 0 until ((2 power to the 24 ) minus 1 )

Comment: I prettified the markdown, it actually supports superscripting which I think is a clearer way to express exponentiation (when available).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Masking with `0xffffff` only makes sure that the value that is stored never is outside the 0..2^24-1 range. Anything but the lower 24 bits are discarded.

If you for example have the value `-1` and mask it, it will end up as the value `0xffffff`. The value has changed, but now it's inside the valid range.

Answer (score 1):

`2**24-1` is `16777215` (here, I've used `**` for the exponentiation).

`0xFFFFFF` is also `16777215`.

In other words, they are two ways of writing the same value.

When you `AND` something with `0xFFFFFF`, you are keeping the 24 least-significant bits, and setting the rest to zero.

Comment: And since some people can't seem to accept that they're the same, "keeping the least-significant 24 bits" is identical to "reduction modulo 2**24" (assuming positive or unsigned values).